# MariaDB homebrew install errors

Tags: macos, homebrew, mariadb

I have just installed MariaDB via homebrew on my Mac. At the end of the installation I got the following error:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mariadb`
```

If I run `brew postinstall mariadb` I get:

```
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/5.5.34/bin/mysql_install_db --verbose --user=andrew --basedir=/usr/loca
MariaDB is hosted on launchpad; You can find the latest source and
email lists at http://launchpad.net/maria

Please check all of the above before mailing us!  And remember, if
you do mail us, you should use the /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/5.5.34/scripts/mysqlbug script!

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Which isn't helpful! The tutorial I was following told me to run `unset TEMPDIR`, then `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=$(brew --prefix mariadb)`; running those results in the following:

```
/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/my_print_defaults: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2)
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
chown: ./data: Operation not permitted
Cannot change ownership of the database directories to the 'mysql'
user.  Check that you have the necessary permissions and try again.
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with the `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d` folder. I've seen this referred to in a couple of things I've tried, but it doesn't exist on my machine. I have tried a few different `mysql_install_db` commands I've found in other tutorials, but they all throw up a (different) error message.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having been unsuccessful with further Googling of the problem I tried manually creating a `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d` and now the `mysql_install_db` command seems to have worked okay. I'm not sure if this is the appropriate solution or if `my.cnf.d` not existing is indicative of a deeper problem with the install but, as things seem to be working, I'll mark as resolved.

[Update] As I was a little unsure in my answer whether this was the 'correct' solution I just wanted to confirm that, after a month, everything is still working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't understand either but creating this folder indeed fixed the issue for me too.

Comment: This totally works but you need to be careful as `brew prune` will remove `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d`. The fix is to replace it manually after `brew prune`, just wanted to give a heads-up.

Answer (score 29):

Just open the config file at `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` with your editor and comment out the following line:

```
!includedir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```

Comment: This was my chosen solution. Adding `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d ` after `brew prune` every time seemed too fragile, and I'm likely to forget when it errors in future. Commenting out that line seems the best solution.

Comment: I just commented the line and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

None of the solution here helped, I had to do this:

[The post-install step did not complete successfully MySQL Mac OS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874931/the-post-install-step-did-not-complete-successfully-mysql-mac-os-sierra)

in short,

- I made a backup of the folder   `/usr/local/var/mysql` , then removed it
- removed Mariadb `brew remove mariadb`
- reinstalled Mariadb `brew install mariadb`
- run `brew services start mariadb`

After that I could access with `mysql -u root`

Comment: Worked in MacOS Mojave 10.14

Answer (score 4):

You might have an orphaned configuration file. I was able to solve this problem by deleting an old `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

### If you're having this problem in 2021

This worked for me:

```
sudo mysql_install_db
sudo chown -R <YOUR USER NAME HERE> /usr/local/mysql # for example sudo chown -R jperez /usr/mysql
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local/mysql
```

After that, running `mysql` or `mariadb` will show the database prompt.

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to have recently gone away.

A simple `bew upgrade` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go

```
/usr/local/mysql
```

and delete the old MySQL file and install again

Answer (score 0):

## For those still having problems with this in 2023

Find and remove my.cnf, mine was located in /opt/homebrew/etc

```
find . -name "my.cnf" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Or more cautiously.

```
find . -name my.cnf
```

Remove my.cnf manually.

```
brew postinstall mariadb
```

Comment: Please do not post scripts that either deletes/removes files without WARNINGS! There are a large group of people out there that grab random scripts from these forums and execute blindly.