# OSX Mavericks can't start mysql

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-mavericks, mysql

So after install OSX Mavericks, i'm trying to start mysql installed by homebrew

the error when i'm trying to do `mysql -u root` or `mysqld`

```
mysql: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 20)
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

I'm researching for a lot of stacks, but i didn't find any error like my, someone can help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448822/mariadb-homebrew-install-errors

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/15071

Comment: Both of those links should answer your question :)