# Cron mysqldump, Can't read dir of '/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2)

Tags: cron, cpanel, mysql

I'm trying to setup a automatic database backup using cron jobs in cpanel that will be emailed to myself, but running into some problems. Currently I have tried 2 different solutions, but getting similar errors.

First I tried this http://www.theblog.ca/mysql-email-backup which is to create a PHP script to be run by a cron job. But I get the error `mysqldump: Can't read dir of '/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2)`

Then I tried this one
http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/hostgator-wolfcms-automatic-mysql-backup.html which is simply running this cron job

```
mysqldump -e --user='<USERNAME>' --password='<PASSWORD>' <DATABASENAME> | gzip | uuencode <FILENAME>.gz | mail <EMAIL>
```

However then I get `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: uuencode: command not found
mysqldump: Can't read dir of '/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2)`

I am on a shared host and did not setup MySQL myself.

So any ideas how I can get one of these to work or even a better solution?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20453251/1816093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uuencode` simply converts binary data (which you got as a result of `gzip` compression) into text data suitable as 7-bit safe "text" data. You can try `base64` instead.

You can try to use better compression as well. So instead of `gzip`, try `bzip2` or even better `xz`, whatever is available.

For `mysqldump`, have a look at the documentation:

- [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)
- [option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)

You can use the option [`--no-defaults`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-defaults) to not try to read any options file. You can also create your own options file (maybe based on some configuration you use somewhere else already) and pass it using [`--defaults-file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_defaults-file).