# MySQL 5.7 installed via brew now getting ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/dev_box.local.pid)

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I had mysql version 8 earlier, due to some dependency i had to downgrade to 5.7 so installed mysql@5.7 via brew.

Steps

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql@5.7
mysql.server start
brew link mysql@5.7 --force
```

Now once i have stopped the server and now i want to restart it but i am getting

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/dev_box.local.pid).
```

When i do

```
mysqld --initialize
```

I am getting

```
[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
[ERROR] Aborting
```

But when i try to start the server using services it's starting but i am not getting anything in the grep but when i do "brew services list" it's showing that server is started.
but i am not able to login

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
```

This gives the error

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

I have tried almost everything from

[MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/8137439)

[After MySQL install via Brew, I get the error - The server quit without updating PID file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating/36156848)

With no luck, hoping for some quick help.

Comment: Was there a mysql error log? That's the place I'd go to -- but since one of the answers to the questions you linked to suggested that, I'm assuming you tried.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman if you are talking about dev_box.err logs then yes, and tried with deleting that as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? As im having similar problems now and exhausting all potential solutions

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation. What helped me is:

First uninstall mysql using brew

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew uninstall mysql@5.7
```

Then manually go through all folders in /usr/local/ and delete everything related to mysql.

For example, I had /usr/local/etc/my.cnf and my.cnf.default, so had to run `rm -f /usr/local/etc/my*`; also /usr/local/mysql-5.7.21-macos10.13-x86_64 and mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64, so `rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*` and so on.

After this is done install using brew

```
brew install mysql@5.7
brew services start mysql@5.7
```